# Можно ли после того, как был получен ответ на вопрос поставить ему заголовок c текстом ошибки?

Tags: обсуждение

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией: те, кто принимают редактуры на вопросы, не могут дать один ответ на эту ситуацию.

Например в [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/734919) правке это не разрешили сделать.

[image: Отказ]

А вот в [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/735345) похожая правка была принята единогласно.

[image: Единогласное принятие]

Я считаю, что после того, как вопрос был принят, нужно изменить его заголовок на такой, чтобы его могли найти как можно больше людей. Ведь для очень многих программистов самым простым способом понять, в чем заключается ошибка - это скопировать ключевую строчку лога и отправить ее в поисковую строку.

А что думаете вы по этому поводу?

Comment: поиск происходит не только по заголовку. В первом случае - строчка лога не делает заголовок понятнее, во втором - делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Почему не стоит ли так делать?**

Копирование ошибок в заголовок - плохая практика. Он не несёт никакой пользы:
его никто не будет читать, он не описывает суть вопроса, ухудьшает его эстетичность. На странице [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) очень хорошо написано про то, каким должен быть заголовок.

**А как стоит делать?**

Заголовок вопроса желательно должен содержать... Вопрос.
Я наоборот стараюсь убирать стектрейсы из заголовков и заменяю их кратким описанием ситуации. Например, вместо этого

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active

лучше что-то такое:

> Почему происходит ошибка "java.lang.IllegalStateException" при работе с таблицами (@JoinTable)?

В прочем, это касается не только стектрейсов, но и слишком общих заголовков, вроде "Проблема с условиями в Android" или "сравнение объектов java".

**На счёт поиска:**

Текст ошибки в заголовке никак поиск не улучшит, это точно, хотя наверно и не ухудшит (но ухудшит сам заголовок, см. выше). В приведённых мною примерах как надо и не надо делать и там, и там встречается "java.lang.IllegalStateException". А ещё для поиска существуют метки =).